# 'find' command suddenly not working in windows hosted agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the YAML file defining our ADO build pipeline we have the following section

```yaml
- bash: |
    pip install pylint
    find preprocessing/ subtyping/ visualisations/ -name '*.py' | grep -v hmm | grep -v /test_ | sort | xargs pylint
  displayName: 'Run linter'
```

At some point in the last week this stopped working. It still works on an `ubuntu-latest` hosted agent, but on Windows (either `windows-latest` or `vs2017-win2016`) it now fails with the message

> FIND: Parameter format not correct

We have not changed anything, but our build process now fails.

- What has changed to cause this failure?
- Why does it only fail on Windows?
- How might I diagnose the problem?
- Is there anything wrong with our call to bash's 'find' command?

Answer (score 2):

Find is a command in Windows that does very different thing to find in a posix shell.

And that would be the error you would get if you ran the Windows find (usually Windows find is located at `C:\Windows\System32\find.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Your PATH may have somehow changed and you're now hitting the Windows `find` instead of the *nix-compatible one.

Try specifying the full path, i.e. `/usr/bin/find` (that's what I see on my windows bash shell when I check with `which find`) instead of just `find` in your build process command.